# Can different algorithm be used in Realm encryption(other than AES-256)?

Tags: xamarin, realm

There is default support for AES-256 in Realm but can we change encryption algorithm to other than AES-256??

Comment: I'm very curious why you'd want to change which encryption algorithm is used, and what algorithm you'd like to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No, it is not a dynamically pluggable system.

The AES Encryption is *baked* into `realm-core`, the shared `C++` library, at compile time and uses the various platform crypto features available (OS / hardware-based). It is open source, so in theory you could write a different provider and handle changes to methods like `realm::util::encryption_read_barrier` and `realm::util::encryption_write_barrier` as needed... or possibly do a paid contract with Realm based upon your custom encryption requirements.

Re: https://github.com/realm/realm-core/blob/master/src/realm/util/aes_cryptor.hpp

```
class AESCryptor {
public:
    AESCryptor(const uint8_t* key);
    ~AESCryptor() noexcept;

    void set_file_size(off_t new_size);

    bool read(FileDesc fd, off_t pos, char* dst, size_t size);
    void write(FileDesc fd, off_t pos, const char* src, size_t size) noexcept;

private:
    enum EncryptionMode {
#if REALM_PLATFORM_APPLE
        mode_Encrypt = kCCEncrypt,
        mode_Decrypt = kCCDecrypt
#elif defined(_WIN32)
        mode_Encrypt = 0,
        mode_Decrypt = 1
#else
        mode_Encrypt = AES_ENCRYPT,
        mode_Decrypt = AES_DECRYPT
#endif
    };

#if REALM_PLATFORM_APPLE
    CCCryptorRef m_encr;
    CCCryptorRef m_decr;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE m_aes_key_handle;
#else
    AES_KEY m_ectx;
    AES_KEY m_dctx;
#endif

    uint8_t m_hmacKey[32];
    std::vector<iv_table> m_iv_buffer;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> m_rw_buffer;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> m_dst_buffer;

    void calc_hmac(const void* src, size_t len, uint8_t* dst, const uint8_t* key) const;
    bool check_hmac(const void* data, size_t len, const uint8_t* hmac) const;
    void crypt(EncryptionMode mode, off_t pos, char* dst, const char* src, const char* stored_iv) noexcept;
    iv_table& get_iv_table(FileDesc fd, off_t data_pos) noexcept;
};
```